# I need to view the phone numbers of a specific contact

Tags: php, html, css, sql, laravel

> this is my controller:

```
 public function viewContacts(){
    $contacts = Contact::with('number')->get();
    return view('contacts.view_contacts')->with(compact('contacts'));
}
```

> this is my view:

```
@foreach($numbers as $number)
<tbody id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>{{ $number->number}}</td>
    <td>{{ $number->type}}</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  @endforeach
```

> in this way, however, I display all the numbers in the table. how can i pass the id of a specific contact and view only their numbers?
>
> this is my table:
> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAct2.png)
> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bkTE.png)

---

> if I use in controller:

```
public function viewNumbers($id){
        $contact = Contact::with('number')->find($id);
    return view('numbers.view_numbers')->with('contact', $contact);
    }
```

}

> and in blade file:

```
@foreach ($contact->number as $number)
<tbody id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>{{ $contact->id }}/{{ $number->number }}"</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  @endforeach
```

> i receive this error: Trying to get property 'number' of non-object

Comment: the same way you can get the id. `{{ $number->id }}`

Comment: @EsTeAa I add a question

Answer (score 0):

use controller code

```
public function viewNumbers($id){
    $contact = Contact::whereHas('number' function($q) use($id){
   $q->where('id','=', $id);
 })->first();
return view('numbers.view_numbers')->with('contact', $contact);
}
```

In Blade

```
@if($contact)
@foreach ($contact->number as $number)
<tbody id="myTable">
<tr>
<td>{{ $contact->id }}/{{ $number->number }}"</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
@endforeach
@endif
```